# SSMS: How can I run transaction backup when my ldf is too big?

Tags: sql-server, ssms, database-backups

I have a SQL Sever database (version 2012) on a full recovery model.  I'm starting to expand my responsibilities into the "admin" side (I have been a query writer up until now).

I have learned that the .ldf file is VERY large (80 GB) in comparison to the MDF (1.5 GB).

I searched online using very simple terms ("why is my LDF file so large?) and see a common response: I need to run frequent transactional backups.  I tried to do exactly that (after first running a full and differential backup) and got a "not enough drive space" error.

Is it too late to run transactional backups now with this database? I was thinking of creating an identical database, copying the data into that second database, and then start a backup routine. I'd then have to do a whole lot of name changes in the many queries and .net pages that rely on the current database name.

Have I been reading incorrectly? Is there a way I can start running transactional backups now or it a lost cause for the database in question?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've already done it, but here's a better answer:

Generally speaking, you *don't* want to shrink the log file.  However, there's something almost certainly wrong here, as the log file probably shouldn't be 50 times the size of the DB.

First, you need to understand how database files work.  The database files get allocated from the file system, and, unless told to shrink, SQL Server never gives it back.  It's almost like a disk partition.  The disk space is there, in reserve, in case the system needs it.  Under proper administration, the DBA knows how much space his Database will need and sets the size accordingly.  He also knows how much his transaction logs need, and sets their size accordingly.  As data is added, updated, and deleted, the amount of data changes but the server never has to ask the OS for more space because it's all planned for!  So, the important step is to understand how your DB is being utilized and how quickly it will grow.  Monitor the usage of the DB file and Transaction Log files, and plan accordingly.  Growth events should be rare once you're at a point where you're purging old data periodically, and transaction log growth events should be minimal unless you have major change operations that are done to the DB.

Next, you need to understand how the [Full recovery model](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms366344(v=SQL.105).aspx) works.  Under the Full recovery model, you must do your normal periodic Database backups *as well as* periodic Transaction Log backups.  Under Full recovery, backing up the Database alone *does not* flush the Transaction Log regardless of what kind of backup you do on the Database.  The only way to flush the Transaction Log (that is, to mark space free for use) is to backup the Transaction Log.  In our environment, we run a Full Database backup every night, and Transaction Log backups every 15 minutes all day on the DBs that are set to Full Recovery.

"But that's a huge pain in the ass!" you say.  "I don't want to back up the Transaction Log, too.  I don't have the backup space, and we don't care if we lose data going back to the last Database backup."

Ah, then you need to ask if you actually need Full Recovery mode.  The only real benefit to Full Recovery mode is point in time recovery.  Let's say Alice in accounting just finishes payroll in the finance system on Wednesday morning just before lunch.  Then, Wednesday after lunch, Bob the CXO accidentally deletes the payroll run from the system.  Oops.  With point in time recovery, you can say, "Restore the DB to right before Bob nuked my paycheck," and Alice won't need to redo all of payroll.

With Simple recovery, you still have DB backups, but you don't worry about transaction logs.  They're still necessary to how the system works for rolling back transactions and such, but they don't help you during database restoration.  The system itself will manage the log space, periodically truncating logs as needed.  You *only* have access to  recovery based on when you back up your Database file, however.  You can't replay logs to get to a point in time.  If you do DB backups every 8 hours, well, you can only recover to when the DB was backed up.  It's all or nothing.

The third method, Bulk Logged, is kind of a split between the two.  You can recover with Transaction Logs and you need to backup Transaction Logs, but you can only recover in chunks.  It's mainly meant for unusual maintenance tasks for Full recovery databases, like a year end rollover and purge where the system is otherwise offline.  It causes the logs to use less space, but it lacks a lot of functionality.  I wouldn't worry about this one if I were you.

If I were you, what I would do is the following:

1. Determine, with the help of your business leadership, what they expect for disaster recovery.  The main question is, "How much time are we willing to lose in the event of a database problem?"  "Database problem" can mean a disk fails or Bob the CXO gets back in the system again and deletes another payroll run.  If you decide you need Full Recovery, then you will have a more complex backup and recovery procedure. You need to backup the database, and also backup the logs.  If you go with Simple recovery, remember that your only protection is the Database backups that you run.
2. Setup your backup as appropriate, either DB only for Simple, or DB and Trans for Full.
3. Monitor your Transaction Log usage.  There's a built-in report in SQL Server Management Studio 2008+ that will show you data file utilization.  Check that before every DB backup and every Log backup.  Simple will be harder to catch because it can truncate (flush) at any point it decides it can, but keep track of it.
4. Test your backups!  Get familiar with how to restore a database!  You can restore a database to a different server or a different DB on the same server.  If you chose Full recovery, play around with point in time recovery.  You want to know how it works *before* you need it.  It's not hard, but like all RDBMSs it is picky as hell.
5. When you're comfortable with how much Log usage your Transaction Logs need, *now* you can shrink your Transaction Logs.  Don't shrink them to 1 MB.  Shrink them to the amount of space you know the system needs.  Give yourself extra space to account for errors.  I would assume that you'd want at least 20% more than your monitoring suggests, but keep in mind that large numbers of inserts, updates, deletes, index rebuilds, table creations, statistics updates, etc. all cause the transaction log to grow.  Basically *every* change in data and metadata is logged there.

One more thing.  When shrinking the Transaction Logs, the first time you do it, it often will not  shrink completely.  Transaction Logs are broken up internally into pages or blocks.  It does not move to the beginning of the file just because the beginning is marked free.  It will use whatever is next until it hits the end of the file, then move to the beginning.  The first time you tell it to shrink, you will very likely just shrink to the page that the system is currently using.  What you do then is keep using the DB, and in a couple hours try it again.  Most likely the Server will have moved to the end of that page and gone back to the start of the Transaction Log file.  You will be able to shrink the Log file to the desired size then.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply run Shrink Log from SSMS and cut the LDF file to small size. There is also option to switch log to simple model and it always be little file. The disadvantage is that you will not be able to do rollbacks of recent operations - but in some cases it is not necessary.

Comment: When doing my basic reading earlier today, I saw references to "NEVER run Shrink Log" -- is this a case where never doesn't mean never?

Comment: OK, you can make backup and then shrink it :) Or switch the recovery model to Simple and the log will be small. It depends the type of DB - how frequently is updated, how critical is the data inside, etc.

Comment: To make sure I'm understanding correctly: 1) run full backup while recovery model is full; 2) shrink database; 3) try running transactional backup; 4) If successful, set up backup schedule or restore backup from #1?

Comment: Uh oh. I tried running Shrink Database and see that only 0.45 MB of 80547.50 MB is available free space. Not good.

Comment: From the full backup you can restore current state but I don't know how many new data can be added after backup? You can shrink only the LDF file.

Comment: Select Shrink File | Log - and look there for the available free space. I suppose it is necessary to switch to Simple recovery model (DB Properties | Options) to enable big shrink. But be sure to have full backup before that.

Comment: I successfully ran Shrink Database > Files > Log. The ldf file size is now about 1.3 GB, which is VASTLY smaller than it was. My idea is to now switch back to FULL and set up my backup maintenance plan. Here goes...

Comment: For my needs, this worked: 1) do a full backup -- as a just-in-case, 2) change to simple recovery type, 3) shrink log file, 4) convert back to full recovery type, 5) (to make sure it worked) run full backup then transactional backup.  Now I can set up my maintenance plan.